# Can VSCode always open a default folder (for Ctrl + P searching) even if opening a file in different folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have VSCode always have a particular folder ("Directory A") open, so the files inside can be searched using Ctrl + P?

It seems the standard behaviour is that my current "added folder" (i.e. "Directory A") get removed whenever I open a file from a different location ("Directory B").

Closing VSCode and re-opening it always returns me to the last used file (i.e. opening "Directory B" and NOT "Directory A").

How can I force VSCode to always have a certain folder open please?

NB, I've looked into "workspaces" but this doesn't help as whenever opening a file not in the workspace, it seems to close the workspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Directory A to your workspace using `File > Add Folder to Workspace...`

Then rather than opening Directory B when you launch VSCode, open the .vscode-workspace file for the workspace that contains both directories.

If there are multiple files in your workspace which match the filename you're searching for using CTRL+P, all the matching files will show up.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, if I do this, then close VS Code, then happen to open up another file in a location not part of this workspace, VS Code automatically closes the workspace so I can't use Ctrl + P anymore. Can I force it to always keep a workspace open, even if opening up other files in different locations?

Answer (score 2):

The solution, at least on linux, is to create a script with the following content (let's call the script `code-standard-path` ):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
code /path/to/standardDir-or-standardworkspace "$1"
```

Then from `caja` right click on a file : `open with` -> `other application`.
Then select the command `code-standard-path` and check `Remember this application for "..." files`.

Now everytime you double-click on the specific file from whatever location, vscode will open in that predefined directory or workspace.

You can move a bit further and pass the standard path as first argument to the script (e.g. use `code "$1" "$2"`). So on the `open with` menu you provide each time the script like this: `code-standard-path /path/to/standardDir-or-standardworkspace`.

This gives you the ability to open a differrent standard path depending on the file you open (e.g. for `.c`, `.java`, `.html`)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. But there is an easy fix:

On the menu bar go to file **File > Preferences > Settings > Window** and **under Restore Windows select** the option **preserve**.

This will ALWAYS reopen the last session, no matter if you start VS from shell, desktop shortcut or by opening a file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open settings File > Preferences > Settings Or by clicking (ctrl + comma)
2. Type "include" in search bar
3. Find "Search > Quick Open: Include History"
4. Uncheck the option